# Express request no longer available on fileStream.on('close')

Tags: node.js, express

I have an implementation of a POST router in node.js with express. The body of the post is a list of files, and the idea is that these files should be zipped and a link to the resulting zip file should be returned. I'm trying to use 'express-session' to store the progress in terms of number of files zipped as well as the file name of the zip upon completion. Updating the number of files zipped (req.session.current) works fine, but for some reason I can't set the file name (req.session.zipFile) in the session when the fileStream closes. I'm suspecting that the req object is no longer valid by the time fileStream.on('close') is reached, but I'm not sure how to handle that. I can't access the session data without a request. 
This is the complete router implementation:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const ZIP_FILES_PATH = require('../constants');


router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
    const json = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
    const path = json["base"];
    if (!path || path.length === 0){
        res.render("error", {msg: "JSON missing 'base'"})
        return;
    }
    const files = json["files"];
    if (!files || files.length === 0){
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.send("JSON missing 'files'");
        return;
    }
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.send("Directory '" + path + "' does not exist");
        return;
    }
    try{
        var sessData = req.session;
            sessData.total = files.length ;
            sessData.current = 0;
            sessData.zipFile = '';
            zipFiles(path, files, req, res);
    }catch(error){
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.send("The files could not be zipped");
        return;
    }
    res.render("zipping")
});
module.exports = router;

const zipFiles = (path, files, req, res) => {
    const zipFile = require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(path).digest("hex") + "_" + new Date().getTime() + ".zip";
    const archiver = require('archiver');
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(ZIP_FILES_PATH + zipFile);
    const archive = archiver('zip', {
    gzip: true,
    zlib: { level: 9 }
    });

    archive.on('error', function(err) {
        throw err;
    });
    fileStream.on('close', function() {
        req.session.zipFile = "/download?file=" + zipFile; //Doesn't stick!
    });
    archive.pipe(fileStream);
    files.map(file => zipSingleFile(path, file, req, archive));
    archive.finalize();

}
const zipSingleFile = (path, file, req, archive)  => {
    fs.existsSync(path + "/" + file) ? archive.file(path + "/" + file, { name: file }) : null;
    req.session.current = req.session.current + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zipFiles()` is asynchronous.  That means it doesn't block and finishes some time later.  So, in the flow of your request handler, you call

```
res.render("zipping")
```

before `zipFiles()` finishes.  And, `res.render()` will send the response and close the output stream.

If you want to wait to call `res.render()` until you're done with the `zipFiles()` call, then you need to either call it from within `zipFiles()` when it's all done or you need to add a callback to `zipFiles()` so it can communicate back when it's done.

Also, is there any reason you can't set `req.session.zipFile = "/download?file=" + zipFile;` before you call `res.render()`?

---

Also, depending upon how you have your session configured (which you don't show us any code for), just doing this:

```
req.session.zipFile  = "/download?file=" + zipFile;
```

may not be enough to actually save that value into the session.  You may also have to call `.save()` on the session.

---

And, you are setting:

```
req.session.zipFile
```

at the end of your zipping process so any requests that arrive from that session before your zipping finishes won't see that session variable set either (this seems like a concurrency problem to me).

Comment: Sorry, I did omit some information that I now see was relevant. The reason I want to render zipping before the zip is done is because this view is showing a progress bar of the zipping. The zipping view is polling with a GET on a sub-route (/zip/polling) to get an update on the progress every 100ms, where it checks if zipFile is set, and if not, checks the value of current to show how many files have been zipped. Because of this, I can't defer the rendering - I wouldn't get a progress bar!

Comment: @JonasRosenqvist - Well, you can't defer the setting of the session variables until it's done if that client is going to be asking for progress before its done.  I'd suggest you show the routes that poll for progress too and add the above information to your question to make your question more complete.  Right now, I don't have enough information on the overall problem you're trying to solve to recommend a specific coding solution - other than pointing out problems in the code I can see.

Comment: Thanks jfriend000. Pointing out that res.render closes the output stream actually really helped. I've already rewritten my code heavily so I'd be hard to post the rest of it they way it used to look. Basically I concluded that I needed a database, so I'm not using redis to write when the zipping is done, and reading from redis when polling. It seems to work fine. Thanks for your help.